# How to add data-validater in add field.?

Tags: magento2.3

I am able to put below data validater in phtml file but unable to finay way to add data validator in addfi

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-english-letter':true}"
```

How to add above in addField ??

```
 $fieldset->addField(
                    'role_name',
                    'text',
                    [
                        'name'        => 'First_name',
                        'maxlength'  =>  '200',
                        'label'    => __('Role Name'),
                        'required'     => true
                    ]
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation class using `'class' => 'validate-english-letter'` in field options.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'role_name',
    'text',
    [
        'name' => 'First_name',
        'maxlength' => '200',
        'label' => __('Role Name'),
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'validate-english-letter'
    ]
)
```

Comment: done but did not get expected result on inspect console.  In inspect console input field tab should be =>    data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-english-letter':true}"

Comment: No, data-validate is uiComponent method so it will be added in the form field only if  the form is created by uiComponent. To add data-validate your form should be based on uiComponent

Comment: with the help of jquery we can do this ? to add in input field: data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-english-letter':true}"

Comment: You do not need to use data-validate for the FORM method. Adding `'class' => 'validate-english-letter'` in field options will work same as the data-validate